# General expression for determinant of a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, exterior-algebra, block-matrices

Consider having a matrix whose structure is the following:

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{7,7} & a_{7,8} & a_{7,9}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{8,7} & a_{8,8} & a_{8,9}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{9,7} & a_{9,8} & a_{9,9}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Question.**

What about its determinant $|A|$?.

**Another question**

I was wondering that maybe matrix $A$ can be expressed as a product of particular matrices to have such a structure... maybe using these matrices:

$$
A_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6}\\
a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6}\\
a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{7,7} & a_{7,8} & a_{7,9}\\
a_{8,7} & a_{8,8} & a_{8,9}\\
a_{9,7} & a_{9,8} & a_{9,9}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I can arrange $A$ as a compination of those: $A = f(A_1,A_2,A_3)$

**Kronecker product**

One possibility can be the Kronecker product:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \otimes A_1 +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \otimes A_2 +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot A_3
$$

But what about the determinant??? There are sums in this case which is not good...

Comment: Look at the definition of the determinant that defines it in terms of the a sum over the permutation group $S_n$.  This will convince you of the idea.  The result is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices).

Comment: @John: Thanks a lot man... didn't see it when looked for it. Please post an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated as a comment, the result is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices).  It really makes block diagonal matrices wonderful, hence finding canonical forms important.

Answer (score 45):

First write
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} A_1 \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ & A_2 \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] && \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&& A_k \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} A_1 \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ & \text{I}_{n_2} \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] && \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&& \text{I}_{n_k} \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \text{I}_{n_1} \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ & A_2 \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] && \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&& \text{I}_{n_k} \end{array} \right] \dots \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \text{I}_{n_1} \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ & \text{I}_{n_2} \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] && \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&& A_k \end{array} \right] $$
Also,
$$\det \left( \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc} \text{I}_{n_1} \hspace{-5pt} &&&& \\[-3pt] & \ddots \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ && A_j \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] &&& \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&&& \text{I}_{n_k} \end{array} \right] \right) = \det (A_j)$$ 
which can be seen by using the cofactor formula and repeatedly expanding along a row or column with all 0's and one 1

$$ \implies \det \left( \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} A_1 \hspace{-5pt} &&& \\ & A_2 \hspace{-5pt} && \\[-3pt] && \ddots \hspace{-5pt} & \\ &&& A_k \end{array} \right] \right) = \det (A_1) \det (A_2) \cdots \det (A_k)$$

Answer (score 7):

1. The determinant of a block diagonal matrix is equal to the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks. In your case, you have a block diagonal  matrix of the form
   $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   A_1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & A_2 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & A_3
   \end{array}\right)$$
   so $\det(A) = \det(A_1)\det(A_2)\det(A_3)$.
2. You can, though it is a bit ad-hoc. For example, note that if we let
   $$T_1 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right)$$
   then $T_1^tA_1T_1$ is the block diagonal matrix
   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   A_1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right).$$
   Likewise, if we let
   $$\begin{align*}
   T_2 &=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right)\\
   T_3 &= \left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{array}\right)
   \end{align*}$$
   then the resulting matrix is
   $$f(A_1,A_2,A_3) = T_1^tA_1T_1 + T_2^tA_2T_2 + T_3^t A_3 T_3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**A "functorial approach" using the exterior product:** If $\phi: V \rightarrow V$ is an endomorphism of a vector space, you may calculate the determinant of the endomorphism $\phi$ as the induced map

$$\wedge^n (\phi): \wedge^n V \rightarrow \wedge^n V$$

where $n:=\dim(V)$. Since $\wedge^n$ is a functor you get a canonical map $\wedge^l (\phi)$ for any integer $l \geq 1$.

It follows $\wedge^n (\phi)$ is an endomorphism of a one dimensional vector space $\wedge^n V$ and hence it is given as multiplication with a number $a$. The number $a$ is the determinant: $a=\det(\phi)$ of the map $\phi$. If you choose a basis $B$ of $V$ and the matrix of $\phi$ in this basis is a matrix $A$, it follows $a=det(A)$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$.

There is a formula:

$$\wedge^{n_1+n_2}(V_1\oplus V_2) \cong \wedge^{n_1}V_1 \otimes \wedge^{n_2}V_2,$$

where $n_i:=\dim(V_i)$. Let

\begin{align*} \phi= \begin{pmatrix} \phi_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \phi_2 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

where $\phi_i$ is an endomorphism of $V_i$. It "follows"

$$\det(\phi)=\wedge^{n_1+n_2}(\phi) \cong \wedge^{n_1}(\phi_1) \otimes \wedge^{n_2}(\phi_2)$$

But the tensor product $\wedge^{n_1}V_1 \otimes \wedge^{n_2}V_2$ is a one dimensional vector space and any linear endomorphism of such a space is given (in a basis) as multiplication with a number. Choosing a basis it follows the endomorphism $\wedge^{n_1}(\phi_1) \otimes \wedge^{n_2}(\phi_2)$ is multiplication with the number

$$\det(A_1)\det(A_2),$$

where $A_i$ is a matrix of $\phi_i$ in a basis $B_i$ for $V_i$.

**Question:** "But what about the determinant???"

By induction it follows that if $M$ is a matrix with square matrices $A_i$ along the diagonal, you get the formula

$$\det(M)=\det(A_1) \cdots \det(A_n).$$