# Determinant of a block matrix, blocks are transformations of the same matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say that $\Phi, U_{11},U_{12},U_{21},U_{22}$ are $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the block matrix:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} 
U_{11}\Phi & U_{12}\Phi \\
U_{21}\Phi & U_{22}\Phi 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $U_{ij}\Phi$ is the usual matrix product. Can anything be deduced about the determinant of this matrix in terms of the determinant of $\Phi$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that

$M=\begin{pmatrix}U_{11}\Phi & U_{12}\Phi \\ U_{21}\Phi & U_{22}\Phi\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}U_{11} & U_{12} \\ U_{21} & U_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\Phi & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & \Phi\end{pmatrix}$.

Then by property $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, the determinant of $M$ is

$\det(M)=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}U_{11} & U_{12} \\ U_{21} & U_{22}\end{pmatrix}\right)\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}\Phi & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & \Phi\end{pmatrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}U_{11} & U_{12} \\ U_{21} & U_{22}\end{pmatrix}\right)[\det(\Phi)]^2$,

where the last step comes from the fact that the determinant of a block diagonal matrix is the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks of such matrix (see [General expression for determinant of a block-diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148532/general-expression-for-determinant-of-a-block-diagonal-matrix)).

Comment: What a beautiful and simple solution - upvote well deserved!